# Pandas .str.isnumeric() for floats?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a column in pandas to keep floats and NaNs. I've found that `.str.isnumeric()` doesn't consider numbers with non-ints as numeric. This surprised me since `pd.to_numeric()` does what I'm looking for (keeps floats and NaNs). So in this example:

```
test_num = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': ['6', '5.5', '4E-05', np.nan, 'bear']})
test_num['col1'].str.isnumeric()
```

I'd expect the output to be

```
0     True
1     True
2     True
3      NaN
4    False
```

But instead it's

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3      NaN
4    False
```

Has anyone else created this kind of basic numeric Series filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour as `str.isnumeric()` checks "whether all characters in each string are numeric" ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html)).

But the question is interesting, because `np.nan` is a `float`, so if you wish to remove `bear` but keep the `nan`, `pd.to_numeric(test_num['col1'], errors='coerce')` will not work, as it converts `bear` to a float (`nan`).

So you could first filter out all values that cannot be converted to `float` prior to running `pd.to_numeric` on the `Series`:

```
def check_numeric(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

test_num = test_num[test_num['col1'].apply(check_numeric)]
test_num['col1'] = pd.to_numeric(test_num['col1'])
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you.

```
pd.Series(np.where(test_num['col1'].isna(), np.nan, 
                   pd.to_numeric(test_num['col1'], errors='coerce').notnull()
                   )).replace({1:True, 0:False})

0     True
1     True
2     True
3      NaN
4    False
```